# Edit Array of Collection in Symfony 3

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine

I have `ArrayCollection` in my controller and I wanted to update the values on the element first before inserting it on the database.

What I tried is:

Get the `ArrayCollection` elements

```
$array = $moneyChanger->getAddTransaction()->toArray();

// Loop the array and update the values
// Once the values are defined, Initiate the Entity for Array of Collection and persist

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

$moneyChanger = $form->getData();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {

   $addAddTransaction = new AddTransaction();
   $addAddTransaction->setForeignAmount($array[$i]->getForeignAmount());
   $addAddTransaction->setPieces($array[$i]->getPieces());
   $addAddTransaction->setRate($array[$i]->getCurrency()->getRate());
   $addAddTransaction->setPesoAmount($array[$i]->getPesoAmount());
   $addAddTransaction->setCurrency($array[$i]->getCurrency()->getCode());

   $em->persist($addAddTransaction);  
}

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($moneyChanger);

}
```

The problem that I encountered was, I got multiple inserted rows, One for the instance that I did, and one for the `ArrayCollection` without no updated values.

Can you help?

Here's the actual array, i wanted to edit the null values on `ArrayCollection`. 
[image]

Comment: Something seems off with your approach.  From your code, you get an array from something existing, then overwrite the variable from your form values, but then persist new transactions from the original array, and the persist the money changer variable without modifying it.

Comment: How to update the elements on array and insert on database?